# iAds for android?

Tags: android

First, I don't know where to ask this question. Well this is programming QA site. So obviously its a wrong place. But I hope people here can answer it. And if there is a site for it, about Android random questions, please provide an url.

I see people on different forums(including SO) talking about they are using iAds for Android, but none of them say how ? I mean iAds by Apple, do they even allow Android users to use their Ads ? I searched all over google but found nothing about it. Are these guys just messing around or what ?

here is one example : 
http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/33530/how-to-increase-ad-revenue (Answer by user20715)

Comment: iAds only Support for iOS not android,iAds alternative Admob is Support iOS,Android,Symbian,Windows Mobile OS!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**`iAds` only supports for iOS not android.
`iAds` alternative `Admob` which supports iOS,Android,Windows Mobile OS!**

Here is More Detail About [Admob](http://www.admob.com)

Welcome..!

Comment: Forget admob. They plaster advertisment everywhere but pay near to nothing. Just google some comparisons between iAd an admob and you might find that you would just be _giving_ away advertisment space.

Comment: Give us examples

Answer (score 3):

**iAd is Not available on android**

Answer (score 0):

iAd only supports for IOS not Android.

Choose a good AdNetwrok that gives you better eCPM. There is lot of AdNetwork available but in my suggestion AdMob is not good for Android.